# static function in class which instantiates object

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I often use a pattern where I have a static member function in a class which instantiates object of itself, uses it, and destroys it.

Is this a good pattern? I think so. Does the pattern have a name?

Comment: for what purpose you do this ?

Comment: Usually for creating gui windows, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's sort of a combination of [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern) patterns. "Singletory" maybe?

Comment: Not exactly. The singleton only allows 1 instance, and the singleton doesn't use itself.

Comment: Ah sorry, a misunderstanding the question on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is called ['Factory method'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

I often use this pattern, if using a factory class is a bit overkill, and when creating an instance of the class is a bit cumbersome (some initialization that has to be done for instance on other objects), or, when you want to have an easy way of creating different types of instances of that class.

Answer (score 0):

are you saying you are doing this

```
class MyClass {
        static void util(){
        obj = new MyClass();
        obj.InstanceMem();
        obj.destroy();
    }

    void InstanceMem(){}
}
```

i see this more of a utility method.

well if you think it solves a common reoccurring problem then it may be called as a pattern.